# Within-subject Mediation analysis

Tags: repeated-measures, spss, mediation

I am trying to find a way to do a mediation analysis between a within-subjects IV and a DV.

I have found the Baron and Kenny approach and path analysis, but I am guessing both apply for a between-subjects design.
I have also found a paper discussing a within-subject mediation analysis using R, but I was wondering whether there is a way to test this through SPSS.

Does anyone know whether this can happen? I am quite new at statistics so please explain as simple as possible..

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. It is more complicated than a between-subject mediation analysis. This [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/s13428-017-0980-9.pdf) explains how to do it and provides an R package. I don't think there is any way to do this in SPSS or JASP.